# Argparse will not recognize arguments

Tags: python, argparse

**This script will print env vars.**
Using Python 3.9.
The goal is to able to run any subcommands if desired. The error I am getting is that if any additional short flags are added, the "ignore environment" arg is trying to parse it. I dont want this. Additional short flags go to anything assigned after `--eval`.

parser.py

```
import argparse, os 

def parseargs(p):
    p.usage = '%(prog)s [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]'
    p.add_argument(
        "-i",
        "--ignore-environment",
        action="store_const",
        const=dict(),
        dest="env",
        help="start with an empty environment",
        default=os.environ,
    )
    p.add_argument(
        "--export",
        nargs=1,
        help="Set argument with --export NAME=VALUE"
    )
    p.add_argument(
        "--eval",
        nargs="+",
        help="Run any commands with newly updated environment, " 
            "--eval COMMAND ARGS"
    )
return p
```

Execution as follows

```
>>> p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parseargs(p) # assigns arguments to parser
>>> p.parse_args('--export FOO=bar --eval cat test.py'.split()) # This is ok and works correctly. cat is the bash command
Namespace([os.environs..], eval=['cat', 'test.py'], export=['FOO=bar']) 
>>>p.parse_args('--export FOO=bar --eval ls -l'.split()) # This is fails
error: unrecognized arguments: -l
```

How do I get "-l" to be overlook by "-i/ignore environment" but passed to eval, like using `cat test.py`. I have tried using sub_parser but to no avail. The same result occurs.

Comment: `--eval ls \-l`?

Comment: @9769953 The shell performs quote removal before the script  is executed; `argparse` will still see `--eval`, `ls`, and `-l`.

Comment: @chepner There is no shell here. But actually, it is parsed as a literal `\` by argparse, upon trying.

Comment: Right, because backslash-escapes are a shell-specific feature. `argparse` doesn't have any such notion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `parse_args` tries to identify *possible* options lexically before ever considering the semantics of any actual option.

Since an option taking a variable number of arguments pretty much has to be the *last* option used alway, consider making `--eval` a flag which is used to tell your program how to interpret the remaining *positonal* arguments. Then `ls` and `-l` can be offset by `--`, preventing `parse_args` from thinking `-l` is an undefined option.

```
p.add_argument(
    "--eval",
    action='store_true',
    help="Run any commands with newly updated environment, " 
)

# zero or more, so that you don't have to provide a dummy argument
# when the lack of --eval makes a command unnecessary.
# Wart: you can still use --eval without specifying any commands.
# I don't believe argparse alone is capable of handling this,
# at least not in a way that is simpler than just validating
# arguments after calling parse_args().
p.add_argument('cmd_and_args', nargs='*')
```

Then your command line could look like

```
>>> p.parse_args('--export FOO=bar --eval -- ls -l'.split())
```

or even

```
>>> p.parse_args('--eval --export FOO=bar -- ls -l'.split())
```

Later, you'll use the boolean value of `args.eval` to decide how to treat the list `args.cmd_and_args`.

**Important:** One wrinkle with this is that you are attaching these options to arbitrary pre-existing parsers, which may have their own positional arguments defined, so getting this to play nice with the original parser might be difficult, if not impossible.

---

The other option is to take a single argument to be parsed internally.

```
p.add_arguments("--eval")

...

args = p.parse_args()
cmd_and_args = shlex.split(args.eval)  # or similar
```

Then

```
>>> p.parse_args(['--export', 'FOO=bar', '--eval', 'ls -l'])
```

(Note that using `str.split` isn't going to work for a command line like `--export FOO=bar --eval "ls -l"`.)

Comment: I didnt know about the  `--`. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

From the [Argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing):

> If you have positional arguments that must begin with - and don’t look like negative numbers, you can insert the pseudo-argument '--' which tells parse_args() that everything after that is a positional argument [...]

So in your case, there are no changes you can make to how you add or define the arguments, but the string you provide to be parsed should have `--` preceding the arguments to the eval option, as such:

```
--export FOO=bar --eval ls -- -l
```

Comment: But then `-l` is a positional argument, not an argument to the `--eval` option. You'll have to adjust the parser significantly.